# How to resolve this Getting Error in Push Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When done some task from terminal it give me message connection closed by foreign host?

Comment: Please post your code. What have you done where do you get that error ?

Comment: 1.  openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out SocialNetworkCert.pem

2.openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out SocialNetworkKey.pem -in     Social_Network_Universe.p12
 
3.cat SocialNetworkCert.pem SocialNetworkKey.pem > SocialNetworkNew.pem

4.telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195

5.openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195   -cert SocialNetworkCert.pem -key SocialNetworkKey.pem when i did this i got an message connection close by foreign host

Comment: Please edit your question and put code there.

Comment: telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195 when i did this i got an error after sometime(10/15 sec).

Comment: Do you want to verify created pem file ?

Comment: i verified pem file  $ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.232.226...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'. after 5 sec i got this message   it saggested me to read error:54

Comment: You can not connect directly to that host. what do you want to do connecting there ?

Comment: to enable push notication service on my device that's why i fallow the steps which is gave in raywenderlich site what is error no:54

Comment: Its normal behaviour what u r facing. In that raywenderlich site its mentioed. in that written that if you see that response you can reach to server and Press Ctrl+C to close connection. So thats natural no issue in that.

Comment: Please edit your question title and explanation, it's totally unclear that you are simply trying to test your APNS certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your certificates, use openssl's client command. Something like

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -prexit -cert Cert.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile CA.pem
```

Obviously, fill in your cert filenames where needed.